# Entity framework not picking up data changes made in SSMS or LinqPad

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, mvvm-light

I'm using EF6 database first, and use the data in a WPF MvvmLight project. If I start the app, and display the patients list, then use either SSMS or LinqPad to change the data (say a name or date of birth), when I refresh the data via the app, it doesn't see the changes. Stopping the app and rerunning it doesn't help, nor does cleaning the solution before rerunning. Sometimes restarting Visual Studio helps, but then sometimes it only shows some of the modified data, not all.

Any ideas why this is happening? It makes it very hard to develop!

Comment: Restarting the app doesn't help? Are you sure you're connected to the same database?

Comment: @blorgbeard Yes, I'm certain. I had that thought and double-checked. As I said, restarting VS can refresh some of the data, so it must be the same database